# How is a polynomial kernel with infinite degree different from RBF Kernel?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, rbf-kernel

I was reading about polynomial and RBF Kernels.

According to my understanding:
Polynomial kernels with degree >1 map the non-linear data into a higher dimensional feature space. Data that aren't linearly separable in input space may be linearly separable in feature space (depending on the particular data and kernel), but may not be in other cases. RBF kernels map the non-linear data into an infinite-dimensional feature space.

I wanted to understand the difference between a polynomial kernel with degree=infinity and a RBF Kernel as, in this case, both of them are in an infinite-dimensional feature space.